# Can arguments be passed like this to a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I found the following code in a project (variable/class names changed):

```
private FragmentParams params;

public static MyFragment newInstance(FragmentParams params) {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.params = params; // <- Manually setting params in fragment class
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    /* The following line initializes a class responsible for the user 
    interface. The params are used for that purpose. However, out of
    nowhere, the params where null 2 times.*/

    presenter.setParams(params);
    return view;
}
```

The project has been live for some weeks and a couple `NullPointerException` were reported when the `presenter` accessed the params (further in the code).

I know the right way is to use `setArguments()`, but the question I would like to ask is: can the pointed line be problematic?

The only thing I can think of is, that Android for some reason re-created the fragment and `params` became `null` due to method `newInstance` not being called, thus, `params` not set.

Comment: No. You can't. You must pass it to `Bundle`.

Comment: Maybe you are instantiating the class like `Fragment()` in some place on the code, without `newInstance` and there the params is `null`

Comment: @Piyush Could you read the last paragraph and tell me what you think about my suspicion?

Comment: @DavidLuque That was a good idea, I just checked and it's not the case. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try setting fragment retain instance state to true, whenever the activity is recreating it will keep the Fragment's instance in Fragment Manager.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be problematic since the argument value is lost when activity is recreated. What you can do is you save the argument value everytime the activity about to destroy via the onSaveInstanceState. Example can be seen [here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en)